# How to render a `pdf file` in a modal in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a personal web page using twitter-bootstrap 3. I want to render a `.pdf file` inside a modal. How can i do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: .PDF in a dialog. Maybe [Google docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer) and [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LW2T6/)

Comment: You could try using an `<iframe>` that directly links to the PDF, but that would require the browser to have the appropriate plugin.

Comment: (Also this question isn't particularly Bootstrap-related.)

Answer (score 2):

It would be relatively similar to using the JQuery UI dialog. (http://jqueryui.com/download/)
You include these scripts inside  tag

```
<link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js"></script>
```

JQuery code

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#trigger').click(function(){
      $("#dialog").dialog();
    }); 
  });                  
</script>
```

HTML code within  (using an iFrame to load the PDF)

```
<a href="#" id="trigger">this link</a>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
    <div>
    <iframe src="yourpdffile.pdf"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question was regarding Bootstrap, not jQuery UI